# how to avoid mutually exclusive data to be input in a field mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to limit input error in a field. The site I am building contains data on cars.

A car can have multiple equipments from a list ( air conditioning, ABS, leather seats, etc..), and I want somehow to keep data entry from making errors, or at least minimize it.

The first case of error is when data is entered for 2 or more mutually exclusive equipments. For instance a car cannot have manual air conditioning AND automatic air conditioning AND automatic air conditioning bi-zone. Only one of those can exist in a car.

The second case of error is when data is entered for a equipment without the pre-requisite. For instance, enter emergency brake assist(BA) without the required ABS. A car can have ABS 
without BA, but BA will exist only in cars with ABS.

The table where data is entered is straight forward. Each car ( version_id ) has multiple equipments(trims) or trim_ids. Version_id and trim_id are FK to table versions and trims, respectively. So the errors of non-existing trim_id or version_id are already taken care of in table versiontrim.

Table versiontrim ( where I want to minimize data error)

```
version_id    trim_id
```

Table trims:

```
trim_id    trim    trimtype
```

Table versions

```
version_id    model_id    version    active    bodytype    places    motor_id    etc...
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: mixing business requirements with data...this sort of things should be handled by the GUI application or application server, not Database

Comment: You can use stored procedures to insert data instead of direct table access, in this case you can do any checks before actual insert or insert any prerequisites

Comment: Thanks Hawili. I was just thinking about your first comment. In a way everything in the databank is driven by business requirement and in the specific case it has to do with consistency of the data. As per stored procedure, I still have to be introduced to it. Will check it out.

Comment: @BernardA it's ok to have some checks at the database level, but ideally those should be a just-in-case line of defence that you never plan to actually hit. Your UI and/or application code should perform similar checks at a higher level in order to provide a better user experience instead of just pushing whatever the user enters into the database, and catching database errors.

Comment: Thanks jcsanyi but I could not disagree more. There's nobody else to hold this bag at higher or lower level. Someone at back office will input the data, via a form or whatever, and WILL MAKE mistakes that if not caught will be seen by my customer, ie, the visitor to the site. It makes no sense to me to create or find a new system to prevent the mistakes. There is certainly tools within mysql to do that. I like, by the way the proposal from Markus Jarderot. It's about solving the problem, not passing it on to somebody else.

Comment: Hi Hawili, I add +1 to you, because in the end I will need to have a stored procedure to perform the solution as proposed by Markus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For each selected trim,
    Retrieve the set of mutually exclusive trims.
    Check if any of those are also selected.
    Retrieve the set of prerequisite trims.
    Check that each of those are also selected.
```

```
create table prerequisites (
    trim_id1 int not null references trims ( trim_id ),
    trim_id2 int not null references trims ( trim_id ),
    primary key ( trim_id1, trim_id2 )
);

create table exclusives (
    exclusive_group int not null,
    trim_id int not null references trims ( trim_id ),
    primary key ( exclusive_group, trim_id ),
    index ( trim_id, exclusive_group )
);

-- Retrieve all prerequisites of selected trims
select p.trim_id1, p.trim_id2
from versions v
inner join versiontrim vt on vt.version_id = v.version_id
inner join prerequisites p on p.trim_id1 = vt.trim_id
where v.version_id = ?;

-- Retrieve all mutually exclusive trims of selected trims
select vt.trim_id as trim_id1, e2.trim_id as trim_id2
from versions v
inner join versiontrim vt on vt.version_id = v.version_id
inner join exclusives e1 on e1.trim_id = vt.trim_id
inner join exclusives e2 on e2.exclusive_group = e1.exclusive_group
where e1.trim_id <> e2.trim_id
and v.version_id = ?;
```

---

You could take this one step further, and just return the conflicts:

```
-- Retrieve any missing prerequisites of the selected trims
select p.trim_id1, p.trim_id2
from versions v
inner join versiontrim vt1 on vt1.version_id = v.version_id
inner join prerequisites p on p.trim_id1 = vt1.trim_id
left join versiontrim vt2
    on vt2.version_id = v.version_id
    and vt2.trim_id = p.trim_id2
where vt2.version_id is null
and v.version_id = ?;

-- Retrieve any selected mutually exclusive trims
select vt.trim_id as trim_id1, e2.trim_id as trim_id2
from versions v
inner join versiontrim vt on vt.version_id = v.version_id
inner join exclusives e1 on e1.trim_id = vt.trim_id
inner join exclusives e2 on e2.exclusive_group = e1.exclusive_group
inner join versiontrim vt2 on vt2.version_id = v.version_id
where e1.trim_id <> e2.trim_id
and vt2.trim_id = e2.trim_id
and v.version_id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. That solves my issue. I made some small adjustments in the queries, as the [versions] table is not relevant for the information I am after( I need to know which version_id has the inconsistencies and that is given by table [versiontrim]. Also added the field version_id in the query field ( again, that's what I am looking for) and removed it from the WHERE clause at the end. Lastly, its important that the order of the fields in table prerequisites is dependant/prerequisite.Thanks again for coming up with solutions, not philosophical stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model these dependencies at database level, you should treat each of these options as a distinct entity.

Because your current structure models an N-N relationship, it also allows the same option being attached several times to a given `version`. You should take the same approach as below for all options.

Mutually exclusive options constitute a "type" of option. For example, the air-conditioning options you describe are a "type of air-conditioning".

For this, create a new entity (eg. `aircond_type`):

```
aircond_type:
    +----+-----------+
    | id | label     |
    +----+-----------+
    |  1 |      none |
    +----+-----------+
    |  2 |    manual |
    +----+-----------+
    |  3 | automatic |
    +----+-----------+
    |  4 |   bi-zone |
    +----+-----------+
```

Then add a foreign key in `versions` to this new table.

As for the interdependant options, the relational way to express a dependency is a foreign key constraint. This means the predicate "version X has option BA" depends on "version X has options ABS", which means modeling each predicate in its own table, with a foreign key constraint between these two:

```
CREATE TABLE version_has_abs (
    version_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT version_fk FOREIGN KEY version_fk_idx(version_id)
        REFERENCES version(version_id)
);

CREATE TABLE version_has_ba (
    version_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT version_fk FOREIGN KEY version_fk_idx(version_id)
        REFERENCES version_has_abs(version_id)
);
```

This is obviously impractical, or at least not flexible. A simple validation trigger could do the check and prevent the attribution of the "BA" option in the absence of the "ABS" option.

Alternatively, for this simple 1-1 dependency, you could treat the "BA" option as a variation of the "ABS" option. This way you would have three "braking" options: "standard", "ABS", "ABS with BA".

Comment: Thanks RandomSeed. Just to your comment on the same option being attached several times to the same version, I failed to mention that the primary key for table versiontrim are fields version_id AND trim_id. So duplication will not happen. As per the rest I will need to sleep on it a bit.